# IBM Watson Visual Recognition Sample for Unity SDK - Custom Classifier not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, image-recognition, watson

I created a new classifier from the Visual Recognition Beta Tool and I am trying to access the new classifier from Unity. In the demo sample I see the classify function should ideally loop through all classifiers found in your bluemix visual recognition service instance.

However when I look at the output log on the console the only classifier that is found is the default classifier.

I know my credentials and the service instance are correct.  Does this mean I should create my new classifier from code instead of doing it in the visual recognition beta tool? I don't see why this would make a difference as the classifier is up and running and works from the web gui.

Its only when I connect to my service instance from unity and test with the sample visual recognition unity SDK that this customer classifier isn't found
 I am not sure why the unity Sdk sample demo does not see my classifier.

Regards
Leon

Comment: Can you post how you are calling the classify method? Does it show your classifier using this curl command? Be sure to replace <yourapikey> with your personal api key

```curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?api_key=<yourapikey>&version=2016-05-20'```

Comment: Hi taj I can see the new classifier using a curl command. However if I test with the unity visual recognistion sample app and try to classify I only see results from the default classifier . my understanding of the sample visual recog code is that the classify button when clicked loops through all available classifiers for a particular bluemix visual recog service instance . my api key is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Recognition service abstraction in the Unity SDK does not iterate through all trained classifiers. Please specify the classifier you would like to use as a string array (classifierIDs).

```
VisualRecognition visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition();

string[] owners = {"IBM", "me"};
string[] classifierIDs = {"default", "<classifier-id>"};
visualRecognition.Classify(OnClassify, <imagePath>, owners, classifierIds, 0.5f);
```

Comment: Thanks taj! I forgot that the classifierids will use the default class if classifier Id is not specified and i guess I looked too deep into the code and confused myself. That library is really well written and actually easy to use. Everything's working 100%

Comment: Awesome, glad to be of service. If the answer is correct can you please mark it correct?  Thanks!